# Difference-in-difference-in-difference using time-series data of unemployment rate testing for changes in rate after policy measure

Tags: time-series, difference-in-difference

Is it possible to make a difference-in-difference-in-difference model with time-series data of unemployment rate for one country (where groups=3 different time periods) testing for changes in rate after policy measure?

I would have a time-series of unemployment rate (monthly) for 3 years. I want to test if the policy measure introduced in the final year in a specific month affected the unemployment rate. Would this approach work?

Comment: Economics Stack Exchange might be a good alternative for posting the question. There might be more experts in DiD and macroeconomics there, though I am not sure.

Comment: Welcome. Did you do *triple* differences already? It appears you want to do a standard difference-in-differences. Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: Seems like a synthetic cohort approach may work here.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you ask for triple diff?
It sounds as if you have only two diffs (Post-Pre and Treated-non-Treated)

For the completeness of the answer, here is an example of simple DiD analysis in R and Stata

### R

```
month<-rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"),as.Date("2012-12-01"),by = "month"),3)
country<-rep(c("UK","US","Spain"),each=36)
unemployment<-rnorm(n=36*3,mean = 0.05,sd = 0.03)
df<-data.frame(month,unemployment,country)

df$after<-ifelse(df$month>=as.Date("2012-01-01"),1,0)
df$treat<-ifelse(df$country=="Spain",1,0)

df$unemployment<-ifelse(df$after==1&df$treat==1,df$unemployment+0.03,df$unemployment)

lm(unemployment~factor(month)+factor(country)+treat:after,data=df)

#If you don't want country and time fixed-effects you could simply write
lm(unemployment~treat*after,data=df)
```

### Stata

I would run something like this

```
reg unemployment i.month i.country treat#after
* and WO fixed-effects:
reg unemployment treat##after
```

Comment: I want to use triple diff because otherwise, the unemployment rate trend has to be the same for the two periods (which are used as groups) for the model to be valid.   There is only one country, so using three different years as groups, and the treatment (policy change) happens in the final year.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but the fact that you have three groups is not the same as three differences. If you have only one difference you can't use diff-in-diff or triple diff.

You can look for stractural break around the policy's change. However, this is not as clean identification as DiD. In other words, you will find correlation rather than causation.

You can't rule out any other unobserved channel that caused the change in unemployment  (covid-19 for example).

Comment: Ah ok, I had misunderstood the DDD then. What I want to do is basically check if a Covid-19 policy measure (such as a furlough scheme) affected the unemployment rate in one country. What approach would you suggest for this?

Comment: @AverageGuy I would update your first answer instead of offered multiple responses/answers.

Comment: I can't think of a better approach. I guess that you may want to look for some type of exogenous variation. Maybe a data on difference level where you could exploit the variation in timing. Or another country that do not use this type of furlough scheme. However, I'm still not convinced that the suggested approachs are good enough

Comment: @OliviaB If you are going with difference-in-differences, then you should look for a non-adopter country. SARS-Cov-2 was fairly widespread. You should also look into synthetic control estimation. This [paper](https://jech.bmj.com/content/jech/72/8/673.full.pdf) seems up your alley.